# A quick check on my MongoDB Query Language

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and there is one question to which I have to write a query wherein the dataset it should accommodate more than 6 people and has exactly 50 reviews. Below is the query I wrote:

```
db.listingsAndReviews.find($expr:{$and:[{"accommodates":{$gt:6}},{"number_of_reviews":{$eq:50}}]}).count()
```

Can somebody crosscheck this real quick. (Thank you fellow developer in advance :D)

Comment: You don't need `$expr:`.

Comment: I tried and it is still not working. "The provided parameters were invalid. Check your query and try again."

Comment: Where are you running the query?

Comment: Mongo Shell as well as on Atlas Cluster